# tables without tabular?

Tags: tables

I'm having a lot of difficulty with the tabular environment. Granted, I'm trying to do a lot, including centering horizontally and vertically, using different fonts in different cells, and different font sizes in different cells.

Worst comes to worst, I can create the table as a picture file and then just embed it, but that puts a bad taste in my mouth because the end-user won't be able to text-search through it. **Is there a different way to make tables other than the tabular environment?** I want to experiment with other options. Other packages are fine of course.

If there's a way to start writing text at any coordinate on the page, that would be just fine. I could then use the drawing functions to draw lines making cells, then put text in there manually. It's not pretty, i mean it wouldn't automatically center or adjust to anything, but no big deal at this point.

For the record, I'm using Xelatex to compile on TexniCenter 2.02 64-bit with the MikTex distribution, on Windows 7 Pro 64 bit. Here's my current code for the table as it exists now. Sorry it's a bit of a mess.

```
    \setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\begin{tabular}[c]{| p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} | p{1.85cm} |}
    \hline
     & \vspace{3mm} \cl{addition} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{subtraction} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{multiplication} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{division} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{exponentiation} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{rootification} \\ \hline 
    \vspace{3mm} \cl{Vortigenu} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{+}} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{-}} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{*}} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{/}} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{\char"5E}} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{\VTGN{\char"40}} \\ \hline
        \vspace{3mm} \cl{Earth} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{+} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{-} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{$\times$} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{$\div$} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{?} & \vspace{3mm} \cl{?} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\setlength{\parindent}{8ex}
```

The page is 28cm by 20 cm, with 2 cm margins on every side. Here are the 2 custom commands as defined in the top-level tex file.

```
\newcommand{\cl}[1]{\centerline{#1}}
\newcommand{\VTGN}[1]{\setmainfont{Vortigenu}{#1}\setmainfont{Times New Roman}}
```

Unfortunately, using `\VTGN{}` seems to create an extra blank line in every cell, making them thicker than necessary. This extra blank vertical space becomes proportionally bigger when i try to scale the font (using `\scalefont{2}`) of the vortigenu cells while keeping the other cells the same font size. BTW that only affects one cell, and all the others dont have bigger size even tho i never put in a `\normalsize` anywhere.

Comment: Can you please show a complete MWE? In this case, I would guess your problems are due in part to your custom macros, so seeing their definitions is necessary to solve the issue...

Comment: The `\VTGN{}` command may have excess white space in it. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) for how you might fix that. TikZ may be the answer to your need to write texts at particular coordinates: see [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) for ideas there.

Comment: I wouldn't use `\centerline` in latex, just use `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{..}` You could use `\begin{picture}` to position text by coordinates but a tabular is usually easier

Comment: please make a self contained complete document that shows the problem, preferably using a standard font so we can run it locally

Comment: In this case, Mico's answer I think is more than enough. But in some cases, I have had problems with tables that only a PGF `\matrixofnodes` could solve.

Comment: Thanks for posting your actual definition of the `\VTGN` macro. I've provided an addendum to my answer to suggest an alternative form of this macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't engage in so much visual formatting. Instead, define some pertinent table parameters -- such as centering the column contents, the heights of the rows, etc -- beforehand, and then create a lean and reasonably easy to read table.

In the example below, I've created a dummy definition of your `\VTGN` macro to make the code compilable. You'll notice a complete absence of `\vspace{3mm}` and `\cl` directives in the code. Observe the use of `\bigstrut` to size the heights of the rows: it's an object with a depth of `4ex` below the text baseline and a height of `6ex` above the baseline. (The strut's *total* height is thus `10pt`.) Adjust these parameters as needed to get the desired spacing. The strut's width is `0pt`; hence it's not visible. One `\bigstrut` per row suffices.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=28cm, paperwidth=20cm, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\newcommand\VTGN[1]{#1} %% just so that this example compiles
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\bigstrut{\rule[-4ex]{0pt}{10ex}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begingroup
\setlength\tabcolsep{0.1pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | *{7}{Y|} }
\hline
\bigstrut & addition & subtraction & multiplication & division & exponentiation & rootification \\ 
\hline 
Vortigenu \bigstrut & \VTGN{+} & \VTGN{-} & \VTGN{*} & \VTGN{/} & \VTGN{\char"5E} & \VTGN{\char"40} \\ 
\hline
Earth \bigstrut & + & $-$ & $\times$ & $\div$ & ? & ? \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I just noticed that you posted the following definition of the `\VTGN` macro:

```
\newcommand{\VTGN}[1]{\setmainfont{Vortigenu}{#1}\setmainfont{Times New Roman}}
```

Using `\setmainfont` in this manner is rather inefficient as well as quite complex; see Section 5 of the user guide of the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package for a more in-depth explanation of this claim. I suggest you provide the following commands in the preamble:

```
\newfontfamily\vtgn{Vortigenu}
\newcommand\VTGN[1]{{\vtgn #1}} % Note the double curly braces
```

This definition of `\VTGN` makes it unnecessary to execute `\setmainfont` twice. Moreover, it works without having to know what the main document font happens to be.

Comment: This is great and much cleaner. I was using tabluar and wasn't aware that tabularx existed. Is it just a modern version of tabular? Can u also explain what the newcolumntype Y and its innards does? I'm experimenting with it and the bigstrut, along with ways to scale the fontsize inside certain cells, which seems to be working except it incurs a slight vertical offset depending on how big a value i use in \scalefont{}

Comment: @user1705043 - The [tabularx package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) is definitely well worth becoming familiar with. The main new column type of that package is called `X`. The virtue of the `X` column type is that LaTeX handles the tedious job of computing column widths. However, cells in an `X` column are set *fully justified* by default. Since you want to *center-set* the cells' contents, it's handy to create a new column type, which I've called `Y`, using the code provided in the answer. Not having access to the special Vortigenu font, I can't offer advice on the other issue you mention.

Comment: thanks this is working great, i even got the main cells' contents to double their font size without too much trouble. I also took ur advice and modified my \VTGN macro. Only thing I dont understand is why my original example made the cells tall just by using \centerline{}, which for some reason seems to add a blank line in each cell, making them thicker.